# rails 4 simple_form as: hidden don't send

Tags: ruby-on-rails, field, simple-form, hidden

I have this code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@uniform) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.association :employee, as: :hidden, selected: @employee %>
    <%= f.association :piece %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Add new piece" %>
<% end %>
```

But, the hidden field ":employee", don't send the selected employee, only send if this "f.association" is not hidden.

My controller is default scaffold:

```
def create
    @uniform = Uniform.new(uniform_params)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @uniform.save
            format.html { redirect_to @uniform, notice: 'Uniform was successfully created.' }
        else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
        end
    end
end
```

I need to send this value of "f.association :employee" but without show in the browser.

Comment: Try with `<%= f.input :employee, as: :hidden, selected: @employee %>`

Comment: f.input don't have 'selected:'

This code works too:
<%= f.input :employee_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: @employee.id } %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just send the `@employee.id` instead?

Like so

```
<%= f.input :employee_id, as: :hidden %>
```

And you can set the value immediately in your controller, e.g.

```
def new
  @uniform = Uniform.new
  @uniform.employee = @employee
  ...
```